# How to set resetToken in React+Graphql?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql

I am having a problem with: my backend generates resetToken for a link in the TriggerResetPassword function after I get a link(http://localhost:3000/reset-password/c10868f7-b64a-4396-925a-3f61468c34ba) where I can change password. But I cannot set the resetToken in my React frontend APP.js. How to make it works?

```
export const RESET_TOKEN = 'reset-token';
```

```
import {GC_USER_ID, RESET_TOKEN} from '../constants'
const resetToken = localStorage.getItem(RESET_TOKEN);
<Route exact path={"/reset-password/:resetToken"} component={ResetPassword}/>
<Route exact path={"/forgot-password"} component={ForgotPassword}/>
```

And my pages are: ResetPassword

```
const RESET_PASSWORD = gql 'mutation ($email:String!, $resetToken:String!, $password:String!) { passwordReset(email:$email , password: $password, resetToken: $resetToken){email,name, resetToken}}';
const { email, password, resetToken} = this.state;
        return(
                <FormControl >
                    < label htmlFor="password">Password </label>
                    <TextField type="text"  value={this.state.password} onChange={e => {this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
                        }}
                    /><br/>
                    <Mutation mutation={RESET_PASSWORD}  variables={{ email, password, resetToken } } onCompleted={() => this._confirm()}>
                        {mutation => (
                            <Button onClick={mutation}>Submit
                            </Button>)}
                    </Mutation>
                </FormControl>
        )

    }
    _confirm = async (resetToken) => {
        localStorage.getItem(resetToken);
        console.log(resetToken);
            this._saveUserData(resetToken);
        };
    _saveUserData = (id,resetToken) => {
        localStorage.setItem(RESET_TOKEN,resetToken);
        console.log(resetToken)   }
}
```

and ForgotPassword:

```
const FORGOT_PASSWORD = gql 'mutation ($email:String!) { triggerPasswordReset(email:$email){ok, resetToken}';
        const { email,resetToken} = this.state;
        return(
                <FormControl >
                     < label htmlFor="password">Email </label>
                    <TextField type="text"  value={this.state.email} onChange={e => {this.setState({ email: e.target.value })
                    }}
                    /><br/>
                    <Mutation mutation={FORGOT_PASSWORD}  variables={{ email } } onCompleted={() => this._confirm()}>
                        {mutation => (
                            <Button onClick={mutation}>Submit
                            </Button>)}
                    </Mutation>
                </FormControl>   )

    }
    _confirm = async data => {
        const { resetToken } = this.state.forgotpassword;
        this._saveUserData(resetToken);
    };
    _saveUserData = (resetToken) => {
        localStorage.setItem(RESET_TOKEN, resetToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your route must be dynamic, have params `<Route path={"/reset-password/:resetToken"} component={ResetPassword}/>` https://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/route-params

Comment: @ThanhTrung thank you. I set it but it says resetToken in undefined, even backend works well. Could the problem b in the export const RESET_TOKEN = 'reset-token';?

Comment: First, remove the keyword `exact`. You are doing dynamic params here, remember? Then when you access the url, it will route to component ResetPassword. Then the token is read from URL and pass through `:resetToken`